# Automatically Start MySQL Server on Startup

Tags: macos, boot, mysql

In the MySQL preferences, I have the "Automatically Start MySQL Server on Startup" selected, but MySQL doesn't start. Starting manually the server through the "Start MySQL Server" button works fine.

[image]

Any thought? Maybe wrong permissions?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X?

Comment: Snow Leopard (10.6.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known problem that the preference pane is (was) broken in 10.6 Leopard. Try reinstalling just the preference pane, not the complete mysql package: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.1/en/mysql-installation-macosx-prefpane.html